# Angular 2 - Looping over an object with dynamic attributes

Tags: angular, object

I need to loop over object in angular2.

my object looks like this

`object = { description: "hi", otherthing: "hello" };`

so this object is dynamic and I need to loop over every attribute ( the number of attributes can change)

Here's the code I have so far

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of errorMessages | keys" class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        {{ item | json }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

this currently shows me `"description"` however when I try to print `{{ errorMessages.item }}` it doesn't show anything.

I'm assuming my syntax is wrong since `item` isn't an attribute of the object, but what's the correct way to print it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not access dynamic properties of an object like that :

try this :

```
{{ errorMessages[item] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In template code Angular6+ version you can you KeyValue pipe as given below to get key as item:

```
<div *ngFor="let keyValuePair of someObject | kevvakye">
  This is the key {{keyValuePair.key}} and this is the value {{keyValuePair.val}}.
</div>
```

You can iterate over object properties like given below in component/typescript code:

```
for (let key in this.ObjectWithAttributes) {
    if (this.concatAttributeWithValues!== '') {
        this.concatAttributeWithValues+= '\r\n';
    }
    this.concatAttributeWithValues+= key + ' : ' + this.ObjectWithAttributes[key];
}
```